# Why env is undefined in this function?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

Here is a javascript file (named `env.js`) that contains some environment configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  "environment": {},
  "mixpanel": {},
  "google": {
    "app-id": "abc"
  },
}
```

I tried to import and use it this way in another javascript written in es6:

```
import env from '../env';

console.log(env)
```

In the dev console, I can see the values have been printed as expected:

[image]

Now I want to unpack the object in a function:

```
const buildArray = () => {

  const entries = [];

  for (let key of env) {
    for (let subkey of env[key]) {
      console.log (env[key][subkey])
    }
  }

  return entries;
};
```

Then I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__env___default.a[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
```

when I comes to the line `for (let key of env)`

If I pause in dev console before this and try to inspect `env` in there, I got  this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: env is not defined
```

But if I introduce the `env` as a parameter to the function, the error went away i.e.

```
const buildArray = (env) => {
```

[image]

Why it is the case? Shouldn't `env` visible in a global scope?

Comment: because env is an OBJECT not an iterable

Comment: perhaps `for (let key of Object.keys(env))` etc

Comment: Thanks for a quick feedback. How to explain the first error `env is not defined` when the function signature is empty?

Comment: no idea - is the import in the same file as buildArray ?

Answer (score 0):

`Key of Object` doesn't work. It should be instead `Key in Object`

`of` keyword is used in `arrays`

```
let a = [1,2,3,4]
for (let item of a) { console.log(item)} // 1 2 3 4
```

`in` keyword is for `objects` (including array)

```
let a = [1,2,3,4]
for (let item in a) { console.log(item)} // 0 1 2 3 (the indexes)

let obj = {a:1, b:2}
for (let key in obj) {console.log (key)} // a b
```